# Runtime error 1004

Tags: vba, loops

I have used the following (simplest) vb code so many times in the same sheet and it always worked but for some reason it now gives me a runtime error

```
Sub Home()
    Application.Goto reference:=Worksheets("Home").Range("a5"), Scroll:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: This will produce 1004 if the worksheet Home is hidden.

Answer (score 3):

This error message seems to mean that the worksheet name `Home` does not exist.

Check whether the sheet name is exactly `Home`, and that you didn't change it by accident.

I can reproduce this error message when I use this code (thus giving an invalid range):

```
 Application.Goto reference:=Worksheets("Home"), Scroll:=True
```

> Run-time error 1004: Method 'Goto' of object '_Application' failed

And, as L42 mentioned, I also reproduced that this method will fail when the worksheet is hidden.

Comment: @user3721539: Need more help?